# Component styling in react-native not rendering consistently within application

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

When viewing my react-native application on an iphone 6 or 6s my some of my components render to the screen as different sizes, or are not visible or flicker between these states. See the following image of `borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth` (taken as a screenshot off of my device)
[image: borderWidth: .3][image: borderWidth: .3]

**What is the best approach for ensuring that my components' styling renders consistently in my iOS application?**

**UPDATE:**
This issue does not only pertain to `borderWidth`... I was able to reproduce on my device with a `View` component, `backgroundColor` and `height:1`.

see basic example here: https://rnplay.org/apps/xUYNIQ (issue visible in emulator is the same issue I am having in my application on my iphone6)

Comment: I have tried dynamically sizing the width based on the `PixelRatio`component https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html however both the 6plus and 6splus share the same ratio of 3. (the 6 plus is the device that renders varying widths)

Comment: Is your simulator zoomed in? i experience the same with scaled down simulator, but it's working fine without scaling.

Comment: This issue occurs on my device. Run and view on your device here https://rnplay.org/apps/xUYNIQ

Comment: Have you tried using StyleSheet.hairlineWidth? It should always be a round number of pixels

Comment: I have tried Stylesheet.hairlineWidth and various forms of logic applied to that number - none of which fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

This may be a precision loss render issue.

I have crashed into a problem like this.I wrote a function to transform styles for different devices, something strange happened : the bottomBorder become extra bold.

The `PixelRatio` get the device pixel ratio info, `Dimensions` get device width and height, but `Dimensions.get('window').width * PixelRatio.get()`  doesn't equal to Apple Device data.

Before I use `PixelRatio` I change it to `parseInt(PixelRatio)`.it won't make any problem,but on iPhone 6 and 6plus components will be smaller.

Comment: While I really appreciate you taking a look @Oboo Chin I think we are dealing with different issues... Within my application the same components are rendering at different sizes. I understand the fact that components will look different across devices but they should not be flickering and rendering at different sizes within my app.

Comment: @MaxwellLasky I copy your code to my project,it works well on iPhone 5s simulator and my iPod touch 5.Only I can reproduce this on iPhone 6s plus simulator when it's in 3/1 mode.I have checked your [demo](https://rnplay.org/apps/KTYjTA) and change the 'height' property to 1/2/3,it still act different.Have you change the 'height' property to a int even number and check it on 100% size simulator or real device?